# Google Json arraylist returning 0 value

Tags: json, spring-4

My Google Json arrylist is returning a 0 value, but shouldn't.

I did not want return this value which have like:

> this--"total":0,"records":0,"page":0,"rows":0,

Below code return this array:

```
[  
  {  
    "message":"sdfghjkl",
    "total":0,
    "records":0,
    "page":0,
    "rows":0
  },
  {  
    "message":"knee problem",
    "total":0,
    "records":0,
    "page":0,
    "rows":0
  },
  {  
    "message":"hip problem",
    "total":0,
    "records":0,
    "page":0,
    "rows":0
  },
  {  
    "message":"patient message",
    "total":0,
    "records":0,
    "page":0,
    "rows":0
  },
  {  
    "message":"hip problem 2-12-2015",
    "total":0,
    "records":0,
    "page":0,
    "rows":0
  },
  {  
    "message":"hip problem 12-2015",
    "total":0,
    "records":0,
    "page":0,
    "rows":0
  }
]
```

Code:

```js
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<PatientDto> all_pati_message = new ArrayList<PatientDto>();
String sql = "";
try {

  sql = "SELECT message from patient_mess";

  ResultSet rs;
  rs = DatabaseConn.getConnection().createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
  while (rs.next()) {
    PatientDto dto1 = new PatientDto();
    dto1.setMessage(rs.getString(1));
    all_pati_message.add(dto1);
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
String jsonString = gson.toJson(all_pati_message);
return jsonString;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>       GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
>         builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation();
>         final Gson gson = builder.create();
> ```
>
> and use annotation of google json like @Expose private String message, in your dto class PatientDto